# Web Server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, centos, web-server, internal-dns

I have a simple concept question regarding to the hostname configuration on DNS server.

I am trying to set-up a webserver where there is an internal address and external address.

Example:
Server name: Puppy.test.com
External address: 198.165.1.51
Internal address: 10.10.8.51

Does that mean I to have to give the external DNS server with puppy.test.com to point to 198.165.1.51
and internal DNS server with puppy.test.com to point to 10.10.8.51

In order to get both address resolvable by the DNS server? (both internal and externally)

Comment: If your server is itself the gateway from 10.0.0.0/8 to the exterior and some internal client tries to make a TCP connection to 198.165.1.51, the OS should route the packet to itself.

Comment: This is not a routing issue. He needs puppy.test.com to resolve to different addresses for internal and external clients. Therefore he needs to configure different addresses in internal and external DNS. So, basically, the answer to the question is: yes, that's exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is called split horizon DNS, and is implemented in Bind with its [views](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-named-configure-views/) feature.

Comment: Thank you folks for answering!!  I will give it a try :)  Greatly appreciated it!!